# Query mongo data if contains a value in an array

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

let's say I have a document with this data structure:

```
type Book struct {
    Title          string   `bson:"title, omitempty"`
    Tags           []string `bson:"tags, omitempty"`
}
```

How should my code looks like if I want to find a book with tags "science fiction" and "horror" (the resulting books can contains more tags than these two)?

Thank you.

Comment: Which driver are you using? What have you tried? What problems do you have? Aim for a [mcve]. Your tag values are "invalid" though, space must not be present after comma and before `omitempty`.

Comment: @icza I have not tried anything since I wasn't sure where to start. I'm currently using Mongo's official driver for Go.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging gave me this:

```
filter := bson.M{
        "tags": bson.M{
            "$all": tags,
        },
    }
collection.Find(ctx, filter)
```